# Find all polynomials $W$ with integer coefficients s.t. $W(n)\mid 2^n -1, \forall n\in \mathbb N$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Let $W$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients, Find all $W$ such that $$W(n)\mid2^n-1, \quad \forall n\in \mathbb N$$
First when $\deg W=0$ we have two solutions, namely $1$ and $-1$, for $\deg W=1$, we set $W(n)=an+b$ (I'll use the notation $W_k$ to denote that $\deg W=k$)
$$W_1(1)\mid 1\implies a+b=\pm1$$
$$W_1(2)=2a+b\mid 3\implies 2a+b=-3,-1,1 \text{ or }3$$

checking all these cases we get some formulas for $W_1(n)$ but unfortunately, they don't work for higher $n$.

The general case is when $\deg W=k$, in other words $$W_k(n)=\sum_{i=0}^na_in^i$$
plugging $n=1$, $$W_k(n)=a_0+...+a_k=\pm 1$$
the issue that I have with this particular problem, is that $W\in \mathbb Z[x]$ and that just creates lots of cases that we wouldn't have if we had instead $W$ has positive integer coefficients.

Comment: $2^n-1$ is, conjecturally, prime for infinitely many $n$. For those $n$, $W(n)$ would have to be $\pm1$ or $\pm(2^n-1)$, but a polynomial can't be $\pm1$ infinitely often (without being constant), nor can it grow as fast as $\pm(2^n-1)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a very elementary way to see why $W = \pm 1$. Suppose the contrary. Then for some $n > 0$ and prime $p > 0$ we have $p | W(n)$. But then $p | W(n + p)$, so we have
$$p | 2^{n} - 1, p | 2^{n + p} - 1.$$
So clearly $p$ is odd. But by Fermat's theorem,
$$2^{n + p} \equiv 2^{n + 1} \bmod{p}.$$
So we conclude that
$$p | (2^{n + 1} - 2^n) = 2^n$$
which is impossible.

Comment: We can also get a contradiction from $2^p\equiv 2 \pmod p\implies 1\equiv 2\pmod p$.